# How to get application header to work

Tags: javascript, xml, api, request, xmlhttprequest

I've been attempting to format an API to get 'application/json' content, yet I still receive it as 'text/html' (which is their default).

Heres's the API code I wrote below:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'my email');
request.onload = function(){
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(data);
}
request.send();
```

Keep in mind I'm very much a beginner and just learned a bit about APIs yesterday.

Comment: Try `request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');`

Comment: I still get back html text :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://icanhazdadjoke.com/` is not an API URL, it's a site page which gets you html and other assets, you need to call API which actually gives you JSON as response.

For example try: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

should do the trick when server is actually giving you JSON data.

Comment: When going through their site, they is says as long as the HTML accept header is set to "application/json" it will reply in JSON data. Im not 100% sure tho..

Comment: @RamanKaur, no it's not.. The site itself may using some kind of APIs to get their data.. RESTful API should be JSON and/or XML by default.
If you open developer tools -> network tab.. you can see their requests and what kind of data this site is loading

Comment: Ah okay I think I understand it now. So the problem basically is that the api url doesn't actually have json data?

Comment: Yup, that URL response is not returning JSON at first place, it loads HTML file.. You need some sort of URL which returns JSON to get this working.

Comment: You can try the URL I provided it's from a site which provides 'Fake Online REST API for Testing and Prototyping' => JSON responses.. so you can check that your request is actually getting some sort of data, and see how API resources should look like.

Comment: request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json'); is basically telling what kind of data to expect, not doing any kind of transformation.. so it should be JSON at first place :D

Comment: Ohh that helps clear it up sooooo much more, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone were to find this thread, the answer above is inaccurate. This endpoint: https://icanhazdadjoke.com/, when requested with the following Request Header:

`Accept: "application/json"`,

Will return the expected data format and not a web page.

Even when I run the original poster's code in my Chrome console, I get the expected result. You may have run into some outage or bug at the time you were using it.

[image]

These jokes are terrible.